# How to secure access to rails server which provides REST API access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rest, devise

How to secure access to rails server which provides REST API access.
We use Devise for authentication.
Our Rails app talks to another Rails server (Service App) and we would like the user to authenticate before accessing the Service App. Should I do it via device authentication token. Kindly advise? What should be done at the service level

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends of your app architecture.
You can use devise to authenticate users at REST API.
But if your Service App is for internal use only, for example it provides data only for another app, you can restrict access by ip, or Basic HTTP auth.

My opinion, that devise is good only for authorising end-users, but not services.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this question is highly opinion based as it stands at the moment.

What is the purpose of the Service App? Does your Rails app consumes frequently from the Service App? Or the other way around? Is it just for logging purposes, like statistics or tag-like resources or critical data like credentials?

From my rule of thumb, if an actual end-user needs to access it to modify a resource (POST, PUT, DELETE) I'd go for token based authentication. If it only needs to read, I might just go with just Basic or none at all, depending on the context.

Either way, I would consider twice if Devise is the precise tool for your own scenario. More than few times I have found myself writing more to actually modify Devise than it would be necessary if I implement my own authentication system. It's not that hard and you learn a lot!